# Join a query for the table of multiple listed foreign ID keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Now I have a query like this:

```
SELECT productorder_key as vt_key, checkin_key as sk_key, product_set_key as vle_key
FROM product_row
LEFT JOIN product_set vle ON vle.key = product_set_key
WHERE sendtime >= FORMAT(GETDATE(), '2019-01-01') AND sendtime <= FORMAT(GETDATE(), '2020-12-31');
```

The result looks like this:

```
vt_key | sk_key | vle_key
-------------------------
FDSDST | GFDDGD | FDSFST
GS4234 | FGFD43 | GD3DFS
```

---

So the question is: How do I bring information from the tables by these foreign keys? There is tables like vt, sk, and vle. For example I should get information of name field of vt table by vt_key. The primary key is the foreign key in the previous result.

Why kind of joins I should do? Or must I use subroutines or something like that?

I haven't the used real data from database. I replaced names of the query.

Thanks colleagues for you help!

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in tabular format

Comment: Might I suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join/6188334#6188334 It explains what each time of join does and is used for

Comment: What you want to do (probably futher joins) depends on what result you want to see. BTW: Please qualify the columns with their table names. What table do `productorder_key`, `checkin_key`, and `sendtime` reside in each?

Comment: Which table does sendtime belong to? It's good programming practice to qualify all columns when several tables are involved. (Like `vle.key`, instead of just `key`.)

Comment: Well actually you've already brought information on that left join. Just add vle.columnName you want to see to the select query such as vle.key or vle.name whatever. You'll see that you already have the data. Then do the same left joins for the other tables :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically using a `LEFT JOIN` is the correct way to fetch data from foreign tables. After joining you could add the table-alias with a star to the projection in order to get all columns for the `vle` table. Or you use `vt.name` to get a specific column.

```
SELECT vle.*, vt.* 
FROM product_row
 LEFT JOIN product_set vle ON vle.key = product_set_key
 LEFT JOIN product_set vt  ON vt.key = productorder_key
WHERE sendtime >= FORMAT(GETDATE(), '2019-01-01') 
    AND sendtime <= FORMAT(GETDATE(), '2020-12-31');
```

As written in the comments above: Always prefix the columns with the table-alias in order to explicitly tell from where the column shall be used.